# Iterate through SimpleXMLElement to retrieve postal code value

Tags: php, xml, geocoding

I am trying to extract the postal code from the Google Geocode v3 API XML Response.  The difficulty I am having is that sometimes the postal_code value is contained in the 6th address_element and sometimes in the 7th.  Here is the XML response that I am working with and in this sample response you can see that the postal_code is the 6th element of the address_component array:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[status] => OK
[result] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [type] => street_address
                [formatted_address] => 177 Church St, Toronto, ON M5C 2G5, Canada
                [address_component] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [long_name] => 177
                                [short_name] => 177
                                [type] => street_number
                            )

                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [long_name] => Church St
                                [short_name] => Church St
                                [type] => route
                            )

                        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [long_name] => Toronto
                                [short_name] => Toronto
                                [type] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => locality
                                        [1] => political
                                    )

                            )

                        [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [long_name] => Toronto
                                [short_name] => Toronto
                                [type] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => administrative_area_level_2
                                        [1] => political
                                    )

                            )

                        [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [long_name] => Ontario
                                [short_name] => ON
                                [type] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => administrative_area_level_1
                                        [1] => political
                                    )

                            )

                        [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [long_name] => Canada
                                [short_name] => CA
                                [type] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => country
                                        [1] => political
                                    )

                            )

                        [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [long_name] => M5C 2G5
                                [short_name] => M5C 2G5
                                [type] => postal_code
                            )

                    )

                [geometry] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [location] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [lat] => 43.6547363
                                [lng] => -79.3763746
                            )

                        [location_type] => RANGE_INTERPOLATED
                        [viewport] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [southwest] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [lat] => 43.6533849
                                        [lng] => -79.3777345
                                    )

                                [northeast] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [lat] => 43.6560829
                                        [lng] => -79.3750365
                                    )

                            )

                        [bounds] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [southwest] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [lat] => 43.6547315
                                        [lng] => -79.3763964
                                    )

                                [northeast] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [lat] => 43.6547363
                                        [lng] => -79.3763746
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I think it should work.

```
$address = $array->result[0]->address_component;
$postal_code = '';
foreach($address as $adr){
    if($adr->type == 'postal_code'){
        $postal_code = $adr->long_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank so much!  It worked perfect.  Been up trying to figure this out for a long time.  Now I can get some sleep.